# I have a button in homepage theme in 2 language

Tags: php

how I can send the user when he click in button learn more when he is in the English home page to about us in English and when he is in the Arabic home page and click go to about us in Arabic language

Comment: What is the URL of the english & the arabic pages?

Comment: You want this dynamically, correct?  If that's the case you'll really need to provide us with some code.

Answer (score 0):

Install the WPML plugin and use another language and add the item to your navigation menu.